# Как получать ответ от юсб принтера используя библиотеку dll winspoll.drv

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, принтер

Всем привет. Есть необходимость получать ответы от принтера после отправки команды на него, принтер использует протокол EZPL. Существует класс RawPrintHelper который обходя драйвера отправляет напрямую команду на принтер. Мне нужно получить ответ от принтера. Существуют утилиты которые дают такую возможность (например GoDoctor). Я сделал свой метод внутри класса RawPrintHelper, но он возвращает пустой ответ. Можно ли вообще получить ответ таким способом, и если можно то как?
Дополненный мною класс RawPrintHelper выглядит следующим образом:

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace GetPrinterResponse;

public class RawPrintHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions: офицальная документация Windows.support
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
    }

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter,
        IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "ReadPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ReadPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, StringBuilder data, Int32 cbBuf, out Int32 pNoBytesRead);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }

                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }

            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }

        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }

        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize; // читает последние символы
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }

    public static bool ReadFromPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out string data)
    {
        // Read the data from the printer.
        Int32 dwError = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        Int32 dwBytesRead = 0;
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false;
        data = "";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
                    // read your bytes.
                    
                    bSuccess = ReadPrinter(hPrinter, sb, 256, out dwBytesRead);
                    data = sb.ToString();
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }

                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }

            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }

        return bSuccess;
    }
}
```

Я добавил сюда метод ReadFromPrinter и ReadPrinter, вероятно там и есть корень зла.
Вызов метода выглядит следующим образом:

```
private void SendCommand()
{
    string printerName = "Godex RT200";
    string cmd = "~S,BUFCLR\r\n~S,SENSOR\r\n";
    SendStringToPrinter(printerName, cmd);
}

private void GetResponse()
{
    string printerName = "Godex RT200";
    Int32 dwCount = 256;
    IntPtr pBytes = new IntPtr(dwCount);
    if (ReadFromPrinter(printerName, pBytes, dwCount, out string response))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
    
    
}
```

Разделил на 2 функции чтобы вручную переждать калибровку принтера и затем получить ответ от него.
Я делал подобное но через ком порт, и все прекрасно работало, только нужно чтоб он принимал ответ по юсб.

Comment: Странный код, его точно не GPT писал? Вы понимаете, что код никак не связан с USB или LPT подключением? Непонятно, работает этот код или нет в принципе, но никаких задержек в нём не предусмотрено. Вы код вообще читали? А документацию по Win API методам, которые используете? Почему решили, что дождаться инициализации возможно именно так? Альтернативы есть?

Comment: код нашел на форумах, про задержку забыл (просто когда я делал через com-порт то без маленькой задержки команда попросту не успевала отправится и сразу требовала ответ) убрать так как изменил код уже, чтобы для начала самостоятельно контролировать вызов методов. Там на форуме у парня была около такой же проблема только принтер был Zebra а не Godex как в моем случае. Как я понимаю используя winspool у меня нет необходимости обращаться к usb портам напрямую, так как эта библиотека находит принтер по его названию в самой винде.

Comment: Окей, этот код не работает? Как вы это поняли?

Comment: `bsuccess` в `rawprinthelper` возвращает false в конце работы. вот и причина. Подключение к принтеру в теории должно быть рабочим тк отправка на него команд работает без проблем. А вот уже с readprinter проблемы однозначно, он пустое значение записывает в `Sb`, следовательно ничего не прочитал

Comment: Вот эту конкретику нужно указывать сразу в вопросе, а не "у меня не работает" и больше ничего.

Comment: Вы правы, нужно было указать. Вопрос просто был в том можно ли так сделать вообще. Просто гдето пишут что через winspool нельзя читать ответы принтера. Я уже экспериментирую с kernel32